# Is there a way to update processor_group variables in a processor in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to update my processor_group variable via a processor. Even ExecuteScript works. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only update the variable registry through the REST API, the same way the UI does.

It is a PUT to /process-groups/{id}/variable-registry:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Just as an update to this Answer:

The nifi url you need is (default basic nifi node):

```
 http://[IP ADDRESS]:8080/nifi-api/
```

The full api url you need to POST an update to an attribute is:

```
 http://[IP ADDRESS]:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/[Process Group ID]/variable-registry/update-requests
```

An example of the payload is:

```
{"processGroupRevision":{"clientId":"c530ce77-0174-1000-fb36-93fa5e92e574","version":6},"disconnectedNodeAcknowledged":false,"variableRegistry":{"processGroupId":"c53cdaff-0174-1000-7922-5285dec53a94","variables":[{"variable":{"name":"authToken","value":"test3"}}]}}
```

To learn more about the payload,  do some variable work in your NiFi UI and watch your developer tools for the "update-requests" entries and pay attention to the [Process Group ID] and the Payload.